# what does this add atachment do in javascript addEventListener

Tags: javascript

Please am having a little difficulty to understand exactly what is the meaning of this attachment in this statements

```
           var x = document.getElementById('myBtn');
           if (x.addEventListner)  {
              //for all major browsers except IE 8 and earlier
              x.addEventlistener('click', myFunction);
           } else if (x.attachEvent)  {
              //for IE 8 and earlier versions
              x.attachEvent('onclick', myFunction);
           }
```

Can anybody tell me what this attachment stuff is all about? I did know addEventListener, but not attachEvent.

Comment: You even have a comment explaining why that part is there. IE8 doesn't know `x.addEventListener`, it, obviously, only knows `x.attachment`.

Comment: It's a Microsoft propietary method that works in old versions of internet explorer. You have comments in the code that helps you to see it

Comment: This is probably the javascript API implemented by IE 8 or older versions. Nothing to get worried about

Comment: Uhm... it really says *`attachment`*?! Sounds like a typo. Especially when in the previous line *`attachEvent`* was used...

Comment: @roal undocumented feature?  It is more likely to be a typo.

Comment: I understand the question. There is no documentation on attachment() for IE

Comment: @PaulH yeah, I totally focused on the comments and didn't even consider `atachment` vs `attachEvent`. My bad.

Comment: i think what you guys are saying is that attachEvent is the alternative that works for Earlier versions of IE

Comment: The space between x. and addEventListner also is a typo

Comment: @pedroyanky To close the quetion, please accept one of the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventTarget.attachEvent()
```

> **Non-standard** - This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

This is a proprietary Microsoft Internet Explorer alternative to the standard `EventTarget.addEventListener()` method.

[image]

**Edit**:

The addEventListener() method **is not** supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, and Opera 6.0 and earlier versions. 
This is what your if statement is validating, to be able to support the other browsers.

Comment: The OP code handles that warning correctly: it only uses it if the standard method does not exist. So that is not the issue in the Original Post

Comment: I see you edited the question. I understood the question differently. The title does not reflect the content any more.

Comment: @PaulH yes it confusing. I edited my answer and explained the why of the if statement. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit: that was the answer to the original question. But this answer is obsolete since the question has been modified since

It is a typo. `x.attachment()` should be `x.attachEvent()`. As documented in the question's code comments, this code is targeted at old IE browsers. So the typo only affects those. They do not have the `addEventListener()` method but have the `attachEvent()` method instead. The code in the question has probably never worked as expected with IE8 or earlier.